# How to write a generic function that creates an HTMLElement using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, class, types

I have a problem. I need to write a common function (class) that can both accept HTMLElements and give them using typescript

An example of attempts

```
class Create {
  protected element: HTMLElement;

  constructor(parent: ParentNode, tag: string, classNames: string, value?: string, attr?: Record<string, unknown>) {
    this.element = document.createElement(tag);
    this.element.classList.add(...classNames.split(' '));
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      this.element.innerHTML = value;
    }
    if ('appendChild' in parent) {
      parent.appendChild(this.element);
    }
    if (attr) {
      for (const key in attr) {
        this.element.setAttribute(key, <string>attr[key]);
      }
    }
  }

  append(element: ElementNode) {
    this.element.append(element);
  }
}
```

This function will be auxiliary to create elements on the page

example of available elements

```
const wrapper = new Create(this.container, 'div', styles.wrapper);
    const headerWrapper = document.createElement('div') as HTMLDivElement;
    const headerNav = document.createElement('nav');
    const headerList = document.createElement('ul');
    const headerLogo = document.createElement('div');
    const headerLogoLink = document.createElement('a');
    const headerLogoTitle = document.createElement('h2');
    headerLogo.classList.add(styles.headerWrapperLogo);
    headerLogoLink.classList.add(styles.headerWrapperLogoLink);
    headerLogoLink.href = '/';
    headerLogoTitle.classList.add(styles.headerWrapperLogoTitle);
    headerLogoTitle.innerHTML = 'Manga Store';
    headerLogo.append(headerLogoLink);
    headerLogoLink.append(headerLogoTitle);
    headerWrapper.append(headerLogo);
    headerWrapper.classList.add(styles.headerWrapper);
    headerNav.classList.add(styles.headerWrapperNav);
    headerList.classList.add(styles.headerWrapperNavList);
    btnHeader.forEach((btns) => {
      const headerListItem = document.createElement('li');
      const headerListItemLink = document.createElement('a') as HTMLAnchorElement;
      headerListItem.classList.add(styles.headerWrapperNavListItem);
      headerListItemLink.classList.add(styles.headerWrapperNavListItemLink);
      headerListItemLink.href = `#${btns.id}`;
      headerListItemLink.innerText = btns.content;
      wrapper.append(headerWrapper);
      headerWrapper.append(headerNav);
      headerNav.append(headerList);
      headerList.append(headerListItem);
      headerListItem.append(headerListItemLink);
```

Or tell me if it is possible to rewrite the "Abstract" class (see example) to get the desired result

```
abstract class Template {
  protected container: HTMLElement;
  static content = {};

  protected constructor(id: string, classNames?: string) {
    this.container = document.createElement('main');
    if (typeof classNames === 'string') {
      this.container.classList.add(classNames);
    }
    this.container.id = id;
  }

  protected header(content: string) {
    const title = document.createElement('h1');
    title.innerText = content;
    return title;
  }

  render() {
    return this.container;
  }
}
```

When I tried this code:

```
const wrapper = new Create(document.body, 'div', '1')
const subWrap = new Create(wrapper, 'div', '2') // ???
```

I got this error:

[image]

Comment: What line is generating that error?

Comment: ```
    if ('appendChild' in parent) {
      parent.appendChild(this.element);
    }
```

Comment: That line produces no error in [this typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBy6nw) Are you sure this is the same code?

Comment: yep, i try add, 

```
const wrapper = new Create(document.body, 'div', '1')
const subWrap = new Create(wrapper, 'div', '2') // ???
```


Error

*Argument of type 'Create' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ParentNode'.
  Type 'Create' is missing the following properties from type 'ParentNode': childElementCount, children, firstElementChild, lastElementChild, and 54 more.*

Comment: Well, that line wasn't in your original question... I'll add it for you and then try to give you an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Create`'s `append` method to support being passed a `ParentNode` or an instance of `Create`, then you just need to type that argument with [a union.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)

For example:

```
constructor(
  parent: ParentNode | Create, // changed this type
  tag: string,
  classNames: string,
  value?: string,
  attr?: Record<string, unknown>
) {
  //...
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=4&ssc=3&pln=4&pc=126#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCBOBTMAXR0DeBYAUNaADvAPZrBoAm0iIiAtogHYoBc0AEgCoCyAMgKK0GzANy5c+YMUYQU8AK7li8ABQEwSZmwAKGpigByxCugA+cJKkQAaaCjABzNrPgBLRg9uhIEA2AYQznLuntAAbmAg8ogA-EFuHraocnHQAEqIUvAUADwuIbbyjADWjMQA7owAfACUmBL4dgAWrhAAdDT0+tAAvNAUxMDywihtwJZogl3MKvYONWJ4jSgt7Z0jY+BQvK2jYBQUKm3H3lB+AW0QBCCuKCoA5ND3NQsN+K4AZtCzAJ4EiMQvhEougemCnvkPM96ktGs1Wh0hPo2u5GIh4Fw+L1wpFoos4QBfN7QT7fe5gAj-RgUWAtEAUR7uQh6Zh1bCwxrqTR7SlMGl0w4rBHrfSvDlEjmklTJeBs4n4D7Kb5SGQoaDFRA-EmMaAyuUcuFCtZI5iXRAoACCKGCACN5GgVBqfrY8sEPFUZQBtJ0AXTFcPwEsJDQlDQpVMOIq0HB4AhNKH1htWiOmPIjKijCfx0AloZwKtk0HK8HD6OxaPKFmQDoGQw2NuMzqeFFcYXutnuAEZnrgC2qIPIbQB1EsEcuISsIauIFTF0vwDsttsdgBM0IA9Oui8pijAPu5EEA)

Comment: protected Title(text: string): HTMLElement {
    const wrapper: Element = new Create(this.element, 'div', style.wrapper);
    const title: HTMLElement = new Create(wrapper, 'h2', 'title', text);
    return title;
  }
(this is part my abstract class)
result >>>>> [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

```
export type Values = string | null | unknown;
export type ParentElem = ParentNode | Create | null;

class Create {
  element: Element;

  constructor(tag: string, classNames: string, parent?: ParentElem, value?: Values, attr?: Record<string, unknown>) {
    this.element = document.createElement(tag);
    this.element.classList.add(...classNames.split(' '));
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      this.element.innerHTML = value;
    }
    parent ? (!(parent instanceof Create) ? parent.appendChild(this.element) : null) : undefined;
    if (attr) {
      for (const key in attr) {
        this.element.setAttribute(key, <string>attr[key]);
      }
    }
  }

  append(element: Create | Node | string) {
    return element ? (!(element instanceof Create) ? this.element.append(element) : null) : undefined;
  }

  remove(element = this.element) {
    return element ? (!(element instanceof Create) ? this.element.remove() : null) : undefined;
  }
}
```

> 

**ternary operators helped me, and a few checks, to protect against surprises in the form of undefind and null, I also created two additional methods for adding and removing elements, maybe it will come in handy for someone)**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).